# Testing Neural Network build from scratch (XOR)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, data-science, xor

So, I have recently implemented a neural network from scratch in python by following 3Blue1Brown's [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDNU6R1_67000Dx_ZCJB-3pi) and I am currently doing the testing part of my implementation. This is done by doing the AND, OR, and XOR problems. It seems like the network works in the AND and OR problems, however, not in the XOR problem. I Get the following predictions:

**AND**

```
Input:     Output:
0, 0       0.048
1, 0       0.018
0, 1       0.020
1, 1       0.974
```

**OR**

```
Input:     Output:
0, 0       0.026
1, 0       0.984
0, 1       0.988
1, 1       0.997
```

**XOR**

```
Input:     Output:
0, 0       0.049
1, 0       0.842
0, 1       0.842
1, 1       0.844 <- WRONG!
```

These results have been predicted with a model of 1 hidden layer with 2 neurons, and the sigmoid function in both the hidden layer and in the output layer.

I have tried different amounts of testing data, epochs, dimensions in the hidden layers, and hidden layers, and nothing seems to work.

So, my question is if anyone has any idea why i get the wrong result in the XOR problem but not in the AND and the OR problems? And if so, how to fix it?

Comment: You might be better off posting on one of the more relevant sites discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms).

Comment: Do you use biased units?

Answer (score 1):

typically the XOR function requires a more complex model. Add another hidden layer of two neurons and that should be sufficient.